# Adding butterscotch syrup in primary

Tags: experiments, alternatives

After some searching around, I've not been able to find butterscotch extract in any nearby stores. I suppose I could order online, but I've realized that there is quite a bit of butterscotch syrup floating around. If I get one with no fat could this cause any problems? I notice that this stuff tends to have some preservatives in it, but I've heard that that isn't always a problem.

Can I put this stuff in during the boil and expect to have a reasonable beer at the end? I'm aiming to still have a nice foamy head at the end.

Comment: Do you have a particular butterscotch syrup you wanted to use?

Comment: I was looking at the ingredients for smuckers, but I don't have any  reason to use that one in particular. If you have a suggestion on which would work best I'm open to it

Comment: most syrups are going to be sugar, milk, and flavoring with a side of preservative. 
check out trader joes if you have one near you for preservative free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used that for brewing but i have for ice cream.

I would add it after the the Lag phase of fermentation, basically in the heart of fermentation, when the yeast is done multiplying, due to the Potassium Sorbate.

I would start this in a small batch, probably gallon or less, or a fast ferment to see how much butterscotch flavor is needed. Then scale it up from there.

personally i would make it myself and take a hit to head retention. butter brown sugar and heavy cream, vanilla is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that a form of "butterscotch" flavour - often found as diacetyl - is a by product of yeast metabolism and can be accentuated by the fermentation process. If diacetyl is really required why not adjust the brewing method and let the yeast do the work. A typical beer that is produced with elevated diacetyl levels in Sam Smiths Tadcaster Special. Generally speaking if one is to add a synthetic (or natural) flavour it is often best added after fermentation is complete or nearly so. The point being that endo and exo yeast metabolism can alter flavours noticeably (eg bio-transformation of hops).